# doesn't dequeue the cell with identifier that exists and is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exception, cell

I set the identifier in in the storyboard file and my code is:

```
@interface SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SLDataSourceObject* dataSource;

@end

@implementation SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _dataSource = [[SLDataSourceObject alloc] initWithDefaultValues];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _dataSource.dataBankURLs[1].count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseableCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell alloc] initWithRow:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I was told that if the class and the identifier are set inside the main storyboard file registering is not needed.

the custom cell class:

```
@interface SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) SLDataSourceObject* dataSource;

@end

@implementation SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell

- (SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell*)initWithRow:(NSUInteger)row {
    self = [super init];

    _row = row;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSURL* imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[_dataSource.dataBankURLs[1] allValues][_row]];
        NSData* imageAsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageAsData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.imageViews.image = image;
        });
    });

    return self;
}
```

but i still get right after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is called

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier reuseableCustomCell - must register a nib or a class
>   for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: In general, you should register for a cell in ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: I did that at first, didn't work, tried it like this, still get the error

Comment: are you added the reusableCustomCell in your storyboard

Comment: when creating a cell class it asked if I want a xib file added, i marked yes, did I miss an include mechanism that was supposed to add the xib into my project?

Comment: Are you aware that you can create **multiple** custom cells directly in the table view in Interface Builder? No need for extra nibs nor explicit registering. The checkbox to create a nib when creating a new view class is an option, it's not mandatory.

Comment: Could you show how you instantiate `SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewController`?

Comment: `SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewController* vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewController"];


            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
     forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reusableCustomCell"];
}
```

and call like

```
 -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reuseableCustomCell";

SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...



cell.xxx.text = [yourarrayNam objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but I tried this as well, same error

Comment: @Spartacus9 - hide this one also [cell awakeFromNib];

Comment: cell = [[SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

the error is right after this line, even after the suggested edits

Comment: updated: removed the xib file and taken @vadian's suggestion

Comment: How can you have 30,000 reputation and not properly format your answers? So lazy.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error, because you put `SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewCell` not in `SLSpuriosCorrelationsTableViewController`, but in `SLSettingsTableViewController`

Comment: This was embarrassing, but I swear this is a new mistake and the error was present before making this mistake

Comment: @Spartacus9 Ok, please show fixed screenshot, that is not working. Btw. `initWithRow` will never be called. May be it's yours previous mistake?